# Using variables from previous ASP page

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

On my first page I have an array defined as:

```
dim selection
    selection = Array("name", "city")
```

On the following ASP page I'd like to call the same variables but I'm having a hard time figuring out how. This has been my basic structure as I attempt different solutions but this does not work, my results are always blank because I don't think I'm calling the variables correctly:

```
dim userselect
    userselect = request.form("selection(0)")
dim cityselect
    cityselect = request.form("selection(1)")
```

If I can do this in VBS great, if I can do this in Javascript, awesome, but I'm not sure where to start and would appreciate some help.

Comment: Web requests are generally stateless. How is the user getting from page 1 to page 2? "following page" Also, what are you actually trying to accomplish? e.g. process a form submit, handle something the user did like an event, or ??

Comment: The items in the array are part of the same select box. This drop down list has a combination of 2 sql columns (name and city) listed as :  `<option value="<% =selection(0) %>"+"<% =selection(1) %>"><% =selection(0) %> :<% =selection(1) %></option>.`  When the user presses the submit button the following page takes the user selection (name : city) and runs an sql query to output additional information about the "name" and "city".

Comment: Well, if it has to be done like that, be sure to use that colon between them for the value, then when it gets submitted as a single value, just Split on the colon, since that's not an acceptable character for a name or city you should be safe doing that. Like, <select name="whatever"><option value="name:city"> and then Request.Form("whatever").Split(":")(0)  (I'm guessing a little on syntax, hope you get the idea)

Comment: How many different ways do you plan to ask the same question?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options,
Or you put the values inside an html form on the first page and post it to the second page and then **request.form** values;

Or you call the second page and pass the values by the caller name (ex. **page2.asp?varname=varvalue**), then you **request.querystring** these values on your second page;
Or you use session variables. Ex.: **session("varname")=varvalue** then you get it on second page by this way **session("varname")**. For example: response.write(session("varname")).

As you're using arrays, things gets complicated, but just a bit. You've already know how to deal with'em.

Comment: I don't really. I've just been stumbling till the page has gotten to this point. Unfortunately this is not really my design. Having the city in the same drop down list was the last thing I wanted to do but it was specifically requested that it be done... Oh, well I guess we can't have everything can we. I'd prefer to go with your first option with some hidden inputs... but every time I've tried that it would either break my page (random format issue) or simply not work. If I remember correctly its just `<input type="hidden" id="userselect" name="userselect" value="<% =selection(0) %>">`